# Save hg changesetID to a file for logging

Tags: tortoisehg

I have a repository that I am maintaining using tortoise Hg. What I would like to be able to do is when I do a commit to save the commits changesetID into a file so I can print it out in the log that is created from the program running.

I have looked into saving a changesetID using:

```
hg id --id > id_file.txt
```

I have also looked into hooks and saw that I can run a command before a commit but I think that I would get the previous commit ID by doing that.

What is the best way to get my changesetID into my programs log?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just select [correct hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) for your action and call from [hook, which fire after commit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook#Commit_Hook)
2. `id_file.txt` is useless file per se inside repository (it doubles `hg id` output, which you always can use in repo), thus - you can [create such file on build|deploy](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/VersioningWithMake) stage only
3. With `hg log -T` you can have free-form output, which may have more information, than plain hash: something like

`hg log -r tip -T "{node|short} ({rev}) - {latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}\n"`

`d153586c28f8 (906) - 0.8.1+4`